# Confused between comparison of asymptotic notation e^n vs 2^2n

Tags: performance, time-complexity, runtime, big-o, complexity-theory

If we compare e^n and 2^2n, then since e > 2 that means 2^2n = O(e^n).
But, I was just wondering if we can assume e > 2 here, and also can we ignore the constants from power as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming here you mean *2<sup>2n</sup>* and not *2<sup>2</sup>n* (writing 2^2n is a bit ambiguous).

You are right that *e > 2* but consider the rules of exponentiation. We have that:

*2<sup>2n</sup> = (2<sup>2</sup>)<sup>n</sup> = 4<sup>n</sup>*.

Now, *4 > e*, so in fact *e<sup>n</sup> = O(2<sup>2n</sup>)*.

And the reverse is not true: *2<sup>2n</sup> ≠ O(e<sup>n</sup>)*. The base of the power does matter in big-O notation as it creates different complexity classes. This constant you cannot ignore.

Comment: ... otherwise  (4/3)ⁿ < (4/e)ⁿ =2²ⁿ/eⁿ → constant as n → ∞, which it doesn't.